Is Bootstrapping Independent Time Series to Construct Prediction Intervals Valid?
Question:
I have a dataset consisting of multiple univariate time series, each representing an independent sequence of insurance claim amounts over time. My goal is to predict future claim amounts using a LSTM model.
Given that classical bootstrapping methods are not directly applicable to time series data due to temporal dependencies, I am considering the following approach:

Each claim is considered to be independent from each other so it follows that each univariate time series is independent.

Create bootstrapped samples by randomly selecting entire univariate time series with replacement (My data consists of over a million claim sequences).

Train a LSTM model on each bootstrapped dataset.

Average the predictions from all the LSTM models to obtain the final prediction and create confidence intervals.


My question is: Is this approach statistically valid and if yes why?
Additional Details:
Each univariate time series is assumed to be independent from the others (e.g., claims from different customers or policies).
By resampling entire time series, I aim to preserve the temporal dependencies within each series.
The goal is to leverage the bootstrapping method to reduce variance and improve the robustness of the LSTM predictions and get a sense of the uncertainty.
I would appreciate any insights or references on the validity of this method and whether it appropriately addresses the challenges of bootstrapping in the context of time series data.
Thank you for your help!
